# Call or Response in Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I want to know the difference between Call And Response ? That when to use **Call** & when to use to **Response** in Retrofit ?

```
@GET("/albums/{id}")
suspend fun functionOne(@Path(value = "id") albumsId:Int):Response<Albums>
@GET("/albums/{id}")
suspend fun functionTwo(@Path(value = "id") albumsId:Int):Call<Albums>
```

These both functions works fine for me, both have different implementations but have almost same purposes.

**1. What way of response type is good for best practices ?**

**2. When to use Response & Call ?**

Comment: if you look at their respective imports, what library are Response and Call coming from? is it from Retrofit or is it OkHttp?

Comment: @Rafa, I'm assuming this is both from Retrofit. Asim, your second function doesn't need to suspend since it has a Call return type.

Answer (score 30):

"Call" is useful when we are willing to use its enqueue callback function.

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<Info>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Info> call, Response<Info> response) {

                Info info = response.body();

                if (info != null && info.getRestResponse() != null) {

                    results = (ArrayList<Result>) info.getRestResponse().getResult();
                    viewData();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Info> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

When we use Coroutines or RxJava in the project(which is the best professional practice) to provide asynchronous execution , we don't need enqueue callback. We could just use Response.

```
suspend fun getMoviesFromAPI(): List<Movie> {
        lateinit var movieList: List<Movie>
        try {
            val response = movieRemoteDatasource.getMovies()
            val body = response.body()
            if(body!=null){
                movieList = body.movies
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            Log.i("MyTag", exception.message.toString())
        }
        return movieList
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

### 1. What way of response type is good for best practices ?

I think it is depends on your use-case. By using `retrofit2.Response<T>`, we can access `errorBody()`(The raw response body of an unsuccessful response.), `code()`(HTTP status code.) or `headers()`(HTTP headers).

### 2. When to use Response & Call ?

- Response: as above
- Call: not necessary because callback type (such as `Call`) replaced by `suspend function`. Second method could be simpler like:

```kotlin
@GET("/albums/{id}")
suspend fun functionTwo(@Path(value = "id") albumsId:Int): Albums
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response . You have cleared my queries very well by giving some additional improvements 

Comment: But if it throws exception then how to know for which url it threw exception?